# Jekyll / Liquid tag list

Tags: liquid, jekyll

Can anyone point me to the definitive list of supported Jekyll Liquid tags?

I'm aware of `{{ contents }}` and a few others from https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/liquid-extensions

But I'm sure there are a lot more.  Can someone help?

I'm particularly interested in predefined output markup - is there a tag that contains "index" when rendering "index.html"?

Comment: it's `{{ content }}` (without the s)

Comment: Hey paperjam, would you accept one of the answers? Was any of this helpful in your research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A list of stock tags can be found on the [Liquid for Designers](https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers) page of the Liquid project.
A list of context data injected into Liquid can be found [here](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Template-Data).

AFAIK, `page.name` contains the source file name, eg *index.md* and `{{ page.basename }}` should output *index* in this case (but I haven't tried it yet).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm aware of `{{ contents }}`

You probably mean `{{ page.contents }}` - `{{ contents }}` alone will render nothing (unless you have defined that variable manually)

> Can anyone point me to the definitive list of supported Jekyll Liquid tags?

The "definitive guide" is: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Template-Data . It lists all the available tags.

> But I'm sure there are a lot more

I'm afraid there are not. By default, for a page, you only get `page.url` and `page.content`. You can also get anything defined on the yaml front. And that's all you can get.

> Is there a tag that contains "index" when rendering "index.html"?

`page.url` will be `index.html`, but there isn't a direct way to get `index` alone (unless you define it manually in the yaml front).

Comment: `{{ content }}` is defined within layouts and is different from `{{ page.content }}`

The former is after parsing all content by Markdown/Textile/Whatever.  The latter is the raw content.  `{{ content }}` is only available in layouts/templates and files included by a layout/template.  `{{ page.content }}` is available everywhere.

Comment: You get a lot more than that.  For example, `site.*`

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll uses Liquid template language, and you can find the list of **tags** and **filters** at the [Liquid Documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics), which can be considered the official reference. There is also a [tutorial for designers](https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers).

The list of [Jekyll-specific **variables**](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) can be found at [Jekyll Documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the [official `github-pages` gem](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/master/github-pages.gemspec#L19), GitHub Pages is currently running version 1.1.2 of Jekyll. Documentation for that specific version is [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/jekyll/1.1.2/index). Digging around there will reveal a few things, such as a few filters not documented at the [Liquid for Designers](https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers) page. For example, I found `{{ page.date | date_to_rfc822 }}` useful when generating an RSS feed for my Jekyll site.

I did not find the above documentation resource complete, but I thought it might be useful for anyone looking at this question looking for additional documentation on what Liquid tags are available in GitHub Pages.